# C# Linq totals of children collections

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Country object which has States. Each state has a Persons collection. (Simplified, but the structure is the same)

I am trying to find out how many people in the country have person.IsAlive==true

I'm trying something like

```
  country.States.SelectMany(e=>e.Persons...).Count
```

but loose it there.

Items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're *really* close. Select the `IsAlive` property, and perform a `Count` on the matching records:

```
country.States.SelectMany(e => e.Persons.Where(p => p.IsAlive)).Count();
```